# Serilog doesn't create logs in MSSqlServer database when in production for .net core 2.1.5 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I created a web application in asp.net MVC with .net core 2.1.5.
This is the only configuration I created in the Startup.cs file for the Serilog:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{          
    ...

    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
       .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            connectionString: Configuration.GetSection("SqlServerConnectionString").Get<string>(),
            tableName: "Logs",
            restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose,
            columnOptions: new ColumnOptions()
        )
       .CreateLogger();

    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }          
}
```

I've created manually the Logs table and I've created a separate migration for it. The Logs entity looks like follows:

```
public class Logs
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Level { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public string Exception { get; set; }

    public string Properties { get; set; }
}
```

The sample of using the logger:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var obj = new { blah = "test12345", blah2 = "fsdf" };
        _logger.LogInformation("sadfsadfsadf",obj);

        return View();
    }
}
```

The logger works when I run the app in the localhost- I can see the logs in the Logs table. However after I deployed the app to production(Azure and some other hosting platform which works based on IIS), I can see the Logs table has been created but it's always empty. Even if I hit the Home/Index action no exception appears, just nothing happens. Any ideas what am I doing wrong and why the app doesn't create logs in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found a workaround. The solution for Azure was to add an `Environment Variable` with value `Development` in the `Application Settings` section in Azure. For the cheap hosting platform, I had to add a `web.config` file:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
      arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
      stdoutLogEnabled="false"
      stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"
      hostingModel="InProcess">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    <environmentVariable name="CONFIG_DIR" value="f:\application_config" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

to the root directory of the .Web project because it works based on IIS. I fixed the problem based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#setting-environment-variables)
Don't really like this solution with adding `web.config` file, because it's not that trivial to manage in the CD pipeline such as JSON file with all the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SqlServerConnectionString correct? Also make sure to call UseSerilog() when you are building the webhost in the Startup.cs. It might be added for dev environment only.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to calling `SeriLog` in the `Program` class on application startup. So try with following:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging => { logging.ClearProviders(); }) // clearing all other logging providers
                .UseSerilog(); // Using serilog
```